# Import list with Import-SPWeb changed certain Urls

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, import

We've exported some lists from one site collection SC1 in web application WA1 with the Export-SPWeb command, and imported it in site collection SC2 in web application WA2 with the Import-SPWeb command.

After some tests, we've discovered that some urls found in rich text or link fields have been changed this way :

1) For urls with _layouts

Before : `https://<WA1_Url>/sites/SC1/subsite1/_layouts/listform.aspx?...`

After  : `https://<WA2_Url>/sites/SC2/_layouts/listform.aspx?...`

2) For urls without _layouts

Before : `https://<WA1_Url>/sites/SC1/...`

After  : `https://<WA2_Url>/sites/SC2/...`

Does anyone have an idea about what's happening and how Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb affect links and urls in list fields values ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the list field column a custom column or OOTB column?

Comment: Columns have been created through UI, based on OOTB field type (no custom solutions)

Comment: Do these columns value point to a location? or values are typed one word by one word manually?

Comment: @Max576_MSFT, manually.

Comment: Import-SPWeb shouldn't change absolute path. Check if the links have been changed to relative paths in your original site.